# How to get available column using MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, join

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcdEF.png]

From tables I need to get all available columns from table "car_type" event if

1. It have car(s) in table "car",
2. It is not 'in use' in table "approval" (if it's using it will show 0 in field car_return)
3. car.car_status is not 0 (if it is show 0 it means this car is fixing, car can't use for some reason)

** If I have 2 vans and in table 'approval' I use it for 1 record it will show only 1 vans available.
Or if I have 2 vans and in table 'approval' I use it for 1 record and in table 'car.car_status = 0' it will not available for use anymore.

I need product like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqsUo.png]

If possible I need product like this

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/yZqap.png]

Ps. sorry for poor in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `[Available]` to come from the approval column.

Your query will be like this

```
select
    car_type.car_type_id,
    car_type.car_type_name,
    count(approval.car_type_id)
from
    car_type
    inner join
    approval 
    on approval.car_type_id = car_type.car_type_id 
where approval.car_return<>0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just add my answer for more details please check for this.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got my answer like this

`SELECT
    tb2.car_type_id,
    tb2.car_type_name,
    (
        tb2.count_car_type - IFNULL(tb1.count_car_type, 0)
    ) AS available
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            car_type.car_type_id,
            car_type.car_type_name,
            COUNT(car.car_type_id) AS count_car_type
        FROM
            car
        JOIN car_type ON car_type.car_type_id = car.car_type_id
        WHERE
            car.car_status <> 1
        GROUP BY
            car.car_type_id
    ) tb2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        car_type.car_type_id,
        car_type.car_type_name,
        COUNT(approval.car_type_id) AS count_car_type
    FROM
        approval
    JOIN car_type ON car_type.car_type_id = approval.approval_id
    WHERE
        approval.car_return = 0
) tb1 ON tb2.car_type_id = tb1.car_type_id
AND tb2.car_type_name = tb1.car_type_name`